# How to make a dash in c#? (Unity 2D)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I am a really inexperienced scripter, so I would be so glad if you could help me. My friend made the movement system and he asked me to implement a dash, that's what he said to me: "I was thinking of just like grabbing a vector at a fixed distance and DOTWEENing to it". This is what I tried to do, unfortunately it doesn't work.

```
        ////GET THE INPUT AS A VECTOR/////
    Vector2 move = playerInput.Player.Movement.ReadValue<Vector2>();
    ////MOVE THE PLAYER/////
    playerRigidbody2D.MovePosition(transform.position + speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime * (Vector3)move);

        /////add a dash key here
        /////if dash and direction pressed
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && move != null)
    {
        playerRigidbody2D.MovePosition(transform.position += (Vector3)move * dashDistance);
    }
```

Comment: I'd start with something like this: `Vector3 move = playerInput.Player.Movement.ReadValue<Vector2>();
Vector2 newPos = transform.position + speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime * (Vector3)move; 
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && move != null) 
{
    newPos += (Vector3)move * dashDistance);
}
playerRigidbody2D.MovePosition(newPos);`

Comment: So, this code isn't working. It's not that is wrong, but if I press space nothing happens :(

Comment: Oh, thats what I get for copying and pasting without really reading. First it's mixing the new  inputsystem (playerInput) with the old `Input` class, and also trying to compare a V3 with null. Maybe create a Button for the player input called Dash with "Press only" trigger. Then you can do `Vector3 move = playerInput.Player.Movement.ReadValue<Vector2>(); Vector2 newPos = transform.position + speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime * (Vector3)move;  if (playerInput.Player.Dash.ReadValue<float>() > 0)  {  newPos += (Vector3)move * dashDistance); } playerRigidbody2D.MovePosition(newPos);`